# Verilog: slow clock generator module (1 Hz from 50 MHz)

Tags: fpga, verilog, clock, clock-speed

I wrote a clock generator module. I think the problem is in my Reg4 module. The errors are:

> ERROR:HDLCompilers:246 - "UpDownCounter.v" line 74 Reference to scalar
> reg 'clk_1Hz' is not a legal net lvalue
>
> ERROR:HDLCompilers:102 - "UpDownCounter.v" line 74 Connection to
> output port 'clk_1Hz' must be a net lvalue

1 Hz clock generator:

```
module slowClock(clk, reset, clk_1Hz);
input clk, reset;
output clk_1Hz;

reg clk_1Hz = 1'b0;
reg [27:0] counter;

always@(posedge reset or posedge clk)
begin
    if (reset == 1'b1)
        begin
            clk_1Hz <= 0;
            counter <= 0;
        end
    else
        begin
            counter <= counter + 1;
            if ( counter == 25_000_000)
                begin
                    counter <= 0;
                    clk_1Hz <= ~clk_1Hz;
                end
        end
end
endmodule
```

Here is my Reg4 bit module:

```
module Reg4(I, Q, clk, reset);
input clk, reset;
input [3:0] I;
output [3:0] Q;
reg [3:0] Q;

reg clk_1Hz = 1'b0;
slowClock clock_generator(clk, reset, clk_1Hz);

always@(posedge clk_1Hz) begin      
    if (reset == 1)
        Q <= 4'b0000;   
    else
        Q <= I;
end
endmodule
```

Can you see the problem in my code?

Comment: You got your answer, but in the future please add a comment telling us which line is the one with the error (line 74, in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Reg4` module, change:

```
reg clk_1Hz = 1'b0;
```

to:

```
wire clk_1Hz;
```

Comment: thanks. It worked but the warning is: CLK Net:value_reg/clock_generator/clk_1Hz may have excessive skew because

Comment: however, my project on basys-2 is working well despite warning

Comment: @cihangirND add a ```BUFG``` primitive between your 1Hz clock register and the output of the ```slowClock``` module. Otherwise the clock signal will be routed on normal routing networks and not the global clock network (which is what the excessive skew warning is about).

Comment: @TomCarpenter wow thanks. 0 warning. did i placed it right ? http://i.hizliresim.com/82a3Ed.jpg

Comment: @cihangirND Indeed. I would have placed it inside the slowClock module for neatness, but when synthesised it will make no difference at all.

Comment: DONE ;););););)[character limit]

Answer (score 1):

In the 1Hz code you haven't assigned any value to the clk_1hz. Hence no value will be assigned to it. Just include assign clk_1hz = counter[24]; outside the always block.